# LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean does not persist with @Transactional

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, transactions

I'm trying to create a project using Spring 4, Primefaces 5 and Hibernate JPA in Eclipse running into Wildfly 8.0 . My project runs fine right now. The only problem is that, `@Transactional` annotation doesn't work. I've tried this (as I saw in another SO question) and it works (This in my DAO):

```
@Repository(value="empleadoDAO")
public class EmpleadoDAO {
    
    @Resource(name="myEmf")
    private EntityManagerFactory em;
    
    private EntityManager emf;
    
    public boolean insertarEmpleado(Empleado emp) {
        boolean res = true;
        emf = em.createEntityManager();
        emf.getTransaction().begin();
        emf.persist(emp);
        emf.getTransaction().commit();
        return res;
    }
}
```

If I do that, it works, but if I use `@Transactional` annotations either in my DAO or in my Service, either using annotation from `javax.transaction` or using `springframework` annotation it doesn't work. It doesn't give me an exception or nothing but if I look into the database it doesn't insert anything (I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3).

Also, currently I'm injecting EntityManagerFactory instead just EntityManager into my DAOs. I tried to inject EntityManager using `@PersistenceContext(unitName="myPersistenceUnit")` but it gives me this error:

```
JBAS016069: Error injecting persistence unit into CDI managed bean. Can't find a persistence unit named myPersistenceUnit in deployment sprisf2.war
```

Here is my `beans.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">

    <context:spring-configured />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <task:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.saplic.sprisf.daos" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.saplic.sprisf.managedbeans" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.saplic.sprisf.services" />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.saplic.sprisf.entities" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="myEmf"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dbDs"></property>
        
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="myPersistenceUnit" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.saplic.sprisf.entities" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">false</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
                
                
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="myEmf" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dbDs" />
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dbDs" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/postgreDS"></jee:jndi-lookup>

    <mvc:resources location="/resources/" mapping="/static/**" />
</beans>
```

Previously it worked starting and committing the transaction in the code without having a `persistence.xml` file, but after that I decided to create one trying to inject `EntityManager` with `@PersistenceContext`.

Here's my `persistence.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    version="1.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myPersistenceUnit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <!-- property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3" /-->
            <!-- property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" /-->
            
            <property name="hibernate.default_schema" value="public" />
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider" />
            
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:jboss/datasources/postgreDS" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I referenced this `persistence.xml` using this property in my `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`:

```
<property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="/META-INF/persistence.xml" />
```

At least I would like to persist my data using `@Transactional` in my services without having to start and commit the transaction through code, and it would be great if I can inject `EntityManager` instead `EntityManagerFactory`.

[EDIT] Here are my files `EmpleadoManagedBean` and `EmpleadoService` from which I call the DAO method for insert:

```
@Component(value="empleadoMB")
@ManagedBean(name="empleadoMB")
@ConversationScoped
public class EmpleadoManagedBean implements Serializable {
    
    @Resource(name="empleadoService")
    private EmpleadoService empleadoService;
    
    private Empleado instance = new Empleado();
    
         public String addEmpleado() {
             empleadoService.insertarEmpleado(instance);
             return "SUCCESS";
         }
}
```

I am sure that instance object is with the necessary data previous to call `insertarEmpleado`. And here's my `Service` class:

```
@Service("empleadoService")
@Transactional
public class EmpleadoService {

    @Resource(name="empleadoDAO")
    private EmpleadoDAO empleadoDAO;
    
    @Transactional
    public void insertarEmpleado(Empleado emp) {
        empleadoDAO.insertarEmpleado(emp);
    }
}
```

[EDIT] By seeing some examples, I saw that some people just declare `<tx:annotation-driven />` and then a bean named `transactionManager`. I changed the name of the bean to `txManager` and it gave me an error indicating that there's no bean with id `transactionManager`, so I think that it injects into the Services but for some reason the annotation doesn't work.

Comment: your em and emf look switched,

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a true answer but it worked for me even when i feel a little bit restricted. I was seeing the Wildfly log generated in eclipse and i saw this:

```
14:58:22,465 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011401: Read persistence.xml for sprisf2
14:58:22,665 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'sprisf2.war#sprisf2'
14:58:22,674 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: sprisf2
    ...]
14:58:22,739 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.5.Final}
14:58:22,741 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
14:58:22,742 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist

14:58:23,410 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) JBAS011409: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'sprisf2.war#sprisf2'

14:58:25,619 INFO  [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean] (MSC service thread 1-3) Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'sprisf2'
14:58:25,619 WARN  [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH015016: Encountered a deprecated javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider [org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence]; use [org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider] instead.
14:58:25,620 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: sprisf2
    ...]
14:58:26,029 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (MSC service thread 1-3) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

According to LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean documentation, it generates a PersistenceInfoUnit by using the information in persistence.xml or if you don't define it, using jpaProperties values, and then you can inject EntityManagers to your DAOs with this bean. As you can see in the log, it generates a PersistenceUnitInfo named sprisf2 (the name of my project), and, when i used this as the persistence unit name:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="sprisf2")
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

And after creating an empty persistence.xml, it worked!! Unfortunately, it seems like i cannot change the PersistenceUnitInfo name even if i specify persistenceUnitName with a different name.

Somebody knows why i cannot change the name? And why do i need to have an empty persistence.xml in order to work?